# Split a map into roughly equal sections directionally and put points in it

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, artificial-intelligence

I have a 16000 x 9000 grid map and I want to split it into x sections that are preferably of equal size. Then I want to place points on each section are centers  of circles with a 2200 unit radius and make sure these circles do not overlap... I want to be able to generate these points somehow as this is for a traversing algorithm I'm making for some AI.

Here's an image to show what I mean:
In this image I have 3 sections[image]

Comment: Please show your attempts, what do you think?

Comment: What is your question actually?

Comment: Trying to find an algo to generate the points